# How to pass 'history' object to stencil.js component <stencil-router>

Tags: javascript, typescript, navigation, stenciljs

I need to use history Object within a Component(`<app-nav>`) which is rendered as a sibling of `<app-root>`

However **I'm completely unable to injectHistory(Appnav) to the component**, according to some tuorials I followed. Always I get an *undefined* log.

Structure as follows:

***app-root.tsx***

```
export class AppRoot {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <h1>Stencil App Starter</h1>
        </header>

        <main>
          <stencil-router>
            <stencil-route-switch scrollTopOffset={0}>
              <stencil-route url="/" component="app-home" exact={true} />
              <stencil-route url="/profile/:name" component="app-profile" />
            </stencil-route-switch>
          </stencil-router>
          
          <app-nav></app-nav>


        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

***app-nav.tsx***

```
import { Component, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
import { RouterHistory, injectHistory } from '@stencil/router';

@Component({
  tag: 'app-nav',
  shadow: false,
})
export class Appnav {
  @Prop() history: RouterHistory
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="app-nav">
        <p>
         Mi navegacion 3
        </p>
        <button onClick={()=> this.draw()}>log history</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  draw(){
      console.log(this.history);      
  }
}

injectHistory(Appnav)
```

***package.json***

```
"@stencil/core": "^2.0.0",
"@stencil/router": "^1.0.1",
"@stencil/store": "^1.4.1",
"@stencil/utils": "0.0.5",
"workbox-build": "^4.3.1"
```

Any idea why I'm getting undefined always?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think `injectHistory` is only available in v2 of the router.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I should look at your code more carefully, you do have RouterHistory - then maybe the reason why it doesn't work is your component (app-nav) is outside of the "stencil-router" (component needed to be referenced via stencil-route **component** prop - might also work with **routeRender()** prop too?)

(original response before adding EDIT above)

For v1 router, you can pass **RouterHistory** as a prop to component (component needed to be included by stencil-route and you don't need to explicitly pass it - stencil does it for you behind the scene)

```
import { RouterHistory } from '@stencil/router';
@Prop() history: RouterHistory;

...

//then use it to manipulate history (say bound this function to button click)
goBackHistory() {
  this.history.goBack();
}
```

[link to Stencil documentation (look under Navigating Programtically)](https://www.serkom.de/docs/routing/)